# Firebase Android SDK causing Gradle error (With no error cause)

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

I am trying to use Firebase in my Android Studio project and it is giving me an empty Gradle error.

I have tried using the Firebase SDK with Gradle, as well as putting the jar in my libs folder and both give the same blank Gradle error.

i have followed the Android quickstart here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

I put in the packagingOptions and that didn't work.  Without an actual error message it's very hard to debug! I haven't written any code for Firebase, i am only trying to get it to run with the Firebase Android SDK without getting a Gradle error

My project works when Firebase is not included.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Nick. I follow the same steps at least once a day to get a working Android app. So most likely there is a difference in how you execute vs how I execute them (or in what we start with). I posted a complete build.gradle below. But besides from that, I will only be able to help if you give more information. What version of Android Studio do you use? Describe step-by-step what you do. Show you build.gradle. Show the error that you get. Is there anything in the Gradle console in Android Studio? etc.

Comment: Hi Frank.  I'm using Android Studio 1.2 

What i do is put the Firebase compile dependency and packagingOptions in the app:build.gradle file in my project, then sync gradle and get no errors.  When i build or try to run the app i get a Gradle error with a blank cause.  

I have commented below with a link to my app:build.gradle file.  It looks fine to me, i can't figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your help guys, it looks like it was a dex limit error.  Adding the Firebase SDK must have put me over the limit, to fix this i had to add **multiDexEnabled true** in the defaultConfig section of my `app:build.gradle` file as well as compile `'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in the dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Have this content in your build.gradle (Module:app)

```
    android {

    //so default auto generated blocks will be here ...

        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }

    } // end of android node 

     dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
            compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you might need to enable multidex.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The complete `app/build.gradle` from one of my projects:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.firebaseuser.nanochat"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1+'
}
```

Comment: sorry, It won't let me post the code here, it says the text is 990 characters too long :/

Comment: There's an *edit* link under your question, so that you can update it with additional information.