# build.gradle error while compiling 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use Firebase to my android app and following the instruction from https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html
to add to my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0+'
}
```

and also

```
android {
    ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

But when i'm running the project. it produce me different error everytime i'm run the project, the error is like this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/firebase/client/android/AndroidPlatform$2.class
```

and this

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/firebase/tubesock/Base64.class
```

Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
}
```

and this is build.gradle for my project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Anyone can help me with this error? any answer would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why you have multidex enabled?

Comment: i have looking for this problem, and i found in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759101/firebase-android-sdk-causing-gradle-error-with-no-error-cause so i'm adding the multidex enabled same with instruction in that post

Comment: Remove that, make a clean, compile again. Lets see

Comment: when i'm removing the multidex enabled, it produce me other error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Post the full build gradle and the one in the root of the project please

Comment: okay i have edited the post, with two build.gradle

Comment: Remove the multidexEnabled and use the gradle plugin with version 1.3.1. Lets see what happens

Comment: i have changed the version build.gradle in root to classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1' , but it still produce me some error like before

Comment: Is is the same error related to transforms?

Comment: this is the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Do you have something in your libs folder? If you remove the firebug dependency does it compile?

Comment: i have firebase-client-android-2.5.0.jar in my libs folder, when i'm remove that jar file from the libs folder. the project not produce me any error again, it can compile

Comment: That is the problem. You cannot have both at the same time, the managed dependency and the dependency in the libs folder.

Comment: I will add this as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the firebase managed dependency in the `build.gradle` and also he firebase jar file in the `libs` folder. Please remove one of them so the project can compile properly.

Comment: does the compile '...' in dependencies required the files that want to be compiled in libs folder? or it looking for that files like downloading from outside of the project?

Comment: The second option. It looks in public repos for this dependency and downloads it for you

Comment: This saved probably a couple of hours!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it could be temporary issue. please try remove and rebuild

```
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0+'
```

after add firebase dependencies and do rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have duplicate dependencies and you have to find out which library has it. Im not sure if you have other modules in your project but i'd do from the command line in root project folder  linux/mac:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies yourCoolProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

you can probably replace yourCoolProject with your modules name such as "app" so for me i ran it like this:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies app:dependencies --configuration compile
```

this will get me all the dependencies for my project as a tree.  Then i can see if those packages its complaining about are listed twice. Then i'd use an exclude so that only one is used.