# gradle build error in firebase dependencies

Tags: java, android, firebase

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.1.0.
>        Required by:
>            FirstApp:app:unspecified
>   Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.1.0.
>        Required by:
>            FirstApp:app:unspecified

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.1.0' 
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.1.0' 
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espres‌​so-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support',
        module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1' 
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: use `10.2.0` version

Comment: Just read the Documentation of firebase there is clearly mentioned the dependencies and exclude options .[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and see [this too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759101/firebase-android-sdk-causing-gradle-error-with-no-error-cause)

Comment: can u paste ur gradle file.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.1.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is a problem with version of library
 In my case i changed the version

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.1.0.             
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.1.0
```

to

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0.             
com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0
```

Comment: Check this link for reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38090248/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration-appdebugapkcopy

Comment: thanks to everyone, by changing version to 10.2.0 and reinstalling repository made my build run success